# How to set up driver for Oracle 12c database on Mac

Tags: macos, drivers, odbc, oracle-12c, oracle-database

I work on a Mac (macOS Mojave 10.14.1) and I am trying to set up an ODBC driver to connect to an Oracle database (my eventual aim is to connect via `R` using the `DBI` package).

I don't have the technical language to express exactly what I need, but I think I need to find out where my driver is and use that in my R code and set it up in my ODBC Administrator tool.

I have been following the instructions on this [Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-the-oracle-odbc-driver-on-macos):

1. Download *Version 12.2.0.1.0 (64-bit) > Base > Basic Package*
2. Download *Development and Runtime > ODBC Package*
3. Unzip and store above files here:  `/Users/my_user_name/Applications/instantclient_12_2`
4. Add files to the macOS library search path `ln -s $(pwd)/libclntsh.dylib.12.1 $(pwd)/libclntshcore.dylib.12.1 ~/lib`
5. Make small patch to the driver name in instantclient_12_2/odbc_update_ini.sh (see link to original instructions)
6. Run the configuration script: `sudo sh odbc_update_ini.sh /usr/local` which returns `*** ODBCINI environment variable not set,defaulting it to HOME directory!`
7. Then I do this: `sudo chown $USER ~/.odbc.ini`

At this point I'm lost. I have found the file `.odbc.ini` here: `/Users/my_user_name/.odbc.ini` (I need to type `ls -l -a`

Now I'm not sure how to connect. I don't know how to add the driver file to my ODBC Administrator, and I can't access it via R.

this is my R code below, I think my driver path is wrong:

```
> con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc()
+                      ,driver = "/Users/my_user_name/.odbc.ini",
+                      ,DBCName = "AUA8"
+                      ,MechanismName = "ldap"
+                      ,uid = 'user_name'
+                      ,pwd = 'my_password')
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/Users/my_user_name/.odbc.ini' : file not found
```

[Here's a picture of my ODBC administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBJij.png) as you can see I can only see my Teradata drivers. I've tried to add an oracle driver but I'm not sure what path to put for my `driver file` and `setup file`.

I'm at my database technical limits here so thanks in advance for your help.